# Any overhead to redundantly setting Control properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm dealing with a lot of code that looks like this:

```
 if (btnLeftDock.BackColor != SystemColors.ButtonFace)
 {
    btnLeftDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 }
 if (btnRightDock.BackColor != SystemColors.ButtonFace)
 {
    btnRightDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 }
 if (btnTopDock.BackColor != SystemColors.ButtonFace)
 {
    btnTopDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 }
 if (btnBottomDock.BackColor != SystemColors.ButtonFace)
 {
    btnBottomDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 }
```

The only reason I can imagine to do this is that there is theoretically some winforms-specific overhead to setting control colors like this:

```
 btnLeftDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 btnRightDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 btnTopDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
 btnBottomDock.BackColor = SystemColors.ButtonFace;
```

I think it's much easier to read, and I can't see any performance difference, but the original developer *must* have had some justification. (right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something special about the BackColor property, it is an *ambient property*.  What that means is that if the property was *never* assigned then the BackColor of the control will be the same as the parent's BackColor value.

That's highly desirable, it provides automatic consistent background color values.  If the parent changes its BackColor then all child controls change it too, to the same value.  As long as they never assigned it themselves.

That might have paralyzed the original author a bit.  But since he used system colors, the test shouldn't be necessary.  I think.

Comment: Is the value snap-shotted when the control is created, or will future changes to the parent's background color affect the control?  If the latter, is there any way to determine the real state of a control's background color?

Comment: @super - logically it is just an internal flag "the BackColor property setter was called".  You cannot find out if the flag is set.

Comment: I hadn't realized that.  I wonder why Microsoft seems to like designing controller properties whose "get" methods don't really return their state?  Having a special color constant for "SameAsParent", along with a ReadOnly "DisplayedBackColor" property, would seem much more useful.

Comment: Well, it *does* return the 'real' value.  The parent's BackColor.

Answer (score 1):

These are buttons, right?

You should find that BackColorChanged is not being fired, so I can't imagine any functional side effects that the original developer is trying to avoid.

Push it to prod :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code from reflector, there does appear to be some minor performance benefit. Nothing of significance though; so I personally wouldn't bother with the check unless the redunant set was identified as a bottleneck. In particular, the `OnBackColorChanged` handler will *not* execute on a redundant set.

---

```
public override Color BackColor
{
    set
    {
        if (base.DesignMode)
        {
            if (value != Color.Empty)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["UseVisualStyleBackColor"];
                if (descriptor != null)
                {
                    descriptor.SetValue(this, false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        }
        base.BackColor = value;
    }
}
```

where `base.BackColor`, defined on `System.Windows.Forms.Control` is:

```
public virtual Color BackColor
{
    set
    {
        if ((!value.Equals(Color.Empty) && !this.GetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor)) && (value.A < 0xff))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("TransparentBackColorNotAllowed"));
        }
        Color backColor = this.BackColor;
        if (!value.IsEmpty || this.Properties.ContainsObject(PropBackColor))
        {
            this.Properties.SetColor(PropBackColor, value);
        }
        if (!backColor.Equals(this.BackColor))
        {
            this.OnBackColorChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect setting a visual property like BackColor will cause the control to get invalidated as the reason for doing this (although still a bit misguided). So an even better solution is to just sandwich these changes between `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` calls, which will cause one invalidation no matter what you do.

Comment: You mean `SuspendLayout` / `ResumeLayout`? Your methods seem to be specific to ListViews or something.